# ANTLR error 134

Tags: java, python, antlr4

I'm trying to build Abstract Syntax Tree for Java in Python with antlr4 package.
I've downloaded Java grammar from
https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java8/Java8.g4

I want to use that grammar file to produce JavaLexer and JavaParser for Python2.

When I say

```
"$ antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python2 Java8.g4"
```

an error occured.That error is

> error(134): Java8.g4:73:0: symbol type conflicts with generated code in target language or runtime

NOTE: I've deleted parts with `Character.isJavaIdentifierPart()`. Because these lines is not proper for python and i will use just ASCII.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python has built-in function called `type`. Antlr4 prints an error for line 73 of the grammar:

```
type
    :   primitiveType
    |   referenceType
    ;
```

Looks like there is a name conflict and you have to rename `type` to something else in your grammar.

Comment: Thanks. That works. **type** keyword is used one time in grammar and I replaced type with typeType.